# Handling Angular 2 http errors centrally

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I have some code that handles all http access in a class that handles adding tokens.  It returns an Observable.   I want to catch errors in that class - in particular authentication problems.  I am an RXjs beginner and can't figure out how to do this and still return an Observable.  A pointer to some fairly comprehensive rxJS 5 documentation (that isn't source code!) would be useful.

Comment: Can you please show some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can leverage the `catch` operator when executing an HTTP call within a service:

```
getCompanies() {
  return this.http.get('https://angular2.apispark.net/v1/companies/')
           .map(res => res.json())
           .catch(res => {
             // do something

             // To throw another error, use Observable.throw
             // return Observable.throw(res.json());
           });
}
```

Another approach could be to extend the HTTP object to intercept errors:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('request...');
    return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });        
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('get...');
    return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });
  }
}
```

and register it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

What to use really depends on your use case...

Comment: I tried the above example but received the following error `error TS2345: Argument of type '(res: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, source: Observable<Response>, caught: Observable<any>) => Observable<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'`. This occurs in the CustomHttp code `return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {`.

Comment: inside the catch add `return Obeservable.throw('Message')`

Comment: Even if I use `return Observable.throw('Message')` I still see the red error messages in my browser console which I would like not to see.

Comment: the `catch` would convert an error to an observable to subscriber, so when I got a global CustomErrorHandler, it cannot capture this kind of errors in a central location